# getting 0000-00-00 00:00:00 TimeStamp using php artisan tinker

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5 terminal base php artisan tinker command to insert data into my table .
my code is :

```
DB::table('songs')->insert(['title'=>'My_Day','created_at'=>'new DateTime','updated_at'=>'new DateTime']);
```

Result is:

> id: "1",
>
> title: "My_Day",
>
> created_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
>
> updated_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

Comment: It helps if you describe the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'created_at'=>'new DateTime'
```

You're trying to set created_at to a string literal `new DateTime`

Drop the quotes

```
DB::table('songs')
    ->insert([
        'title'=>'My_Day',
        'created_at'=> new DateTime(),
        'updated_at'=> new DateTime()
    ]);
```

Better yet, let Laravel do it for you